# Java gRPC get the service name from ServerInterceptor

Tags: java, grpc, proto

I am using gRPC and I need to get the name of the service of the request from the ServerInterceptor but it seems it is not possible.

Basically from an implementation of *ServerInterceptor* I need to know the name of the ServiceGrpc (as a string) that will be invoked.

```
public class PermissionInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

        @Override
        public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
                ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall, Metadata metadata, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> handler
        ) {
            // here I need the name of RPC service that has been requested

            return handler.startCall(serverCall, metadata);
        }
}
```

Please note that I have tried with *serverCall.getMethodDescriptor()* but it returns the name of the *proto* service rather than the *real* name of the (java) service.

It returns:

```
co.test.domain.transaction.TransactionService
```

But I need this:

```
co.test.domain.transaction.TransactionNeoBasicImpl
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible.

If your interceptor is the last one before the application, you may be able to inspect `handler`'s class and see its parent class' name. But that's very limited and not necessarily supported.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So there's no way to read the annotations present in the TransactionNeoBasicImpl class from the ServerInterceptor. Am I correct?

Comment: Correct. You can't from an interceptor without manual plumbing.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do this.

```
String fullMethodName = serverCall.getMethodDescriptor().getFullMethodName();
String serviceName = MethodDescriptor.extractFullServiceName(fullMethodName);
```

Basically fullMethodName has the fully qualified service name as prefix (followed by a '`/`'). Something like this `fullyqualified.ServiceName/MethodName`